# Unknown caller android

Tags: android, call, ddms, simulate

I am developing applicaton that listens for different user calls. One of possibilites is that unknown caller will call me (without number/ restricted number). I would like to study this case, how I can simulate such call in DDMS enviroment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the DDMS view, Emulator Control, at Telephony Action you can enter a specific number, or to simulate unknown caller try leaving the field blank.
EDIT: place `#` in the Incoming number field.

Comment: Actually you can't press call if number is empty

Comment: You can connect to emulator with telnet: `telnet localhost 5554` and then run `gsm call #`. This makes a call using # and the emulator receives call as unknown.

Comment: Actually I tried it on Telephony Action as well, you have to set # in the Incoming number field.